# How to add symbols in layers?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am looking to know how to add an object inside a Layer, as you can see here :

[image: 1]

I can't find a way to actually add my Movieclip inside the layer from the code side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no. Long answer, I don't think you can, layers are more like grouped display order. I've been using Flash for years and have never met this need or issue. You add the mc from the code at runtime, a moment where you don't really care which layer it goes into.

However, if your question is actually, how to add a mc at a specific index, then you can either addChildAt( mc, theIndexYouWant) or, simulate the layers by creating movieclips and inserting what you need inside of it.

In this case, you would have, on the stage, in a single layer, the movieclips: floor, toto, layer2 and layer3. You would then add, using the code, the mc you want in the toto movieclip.

If something is unclear, ask away :)

Comment: addChildAt (mc , index) Works Good enough for me, Thanks :) wish I could vote up your answer

Comment: you are welcome! just be active on stackoverflow and you will get the ability :D cheers